# Index Name Not Being Set in Filebeat to Elasticsearch - ELK .NET Docker ElasticHQ

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, filebeat

I am experimenting with some `json` that has been formatted in accordance with `Elasticsearch`, so I have gone directly from `Filebeat` to Elasticsearch, as opposed to going through `Logstash`. This is using `docker-compose`:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.2
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - cluster.name=docker-
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - esnet
  filebeat:
    container_name: filebeat
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: filebeat.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/var/log
      - ./filebeat/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
    networks:
      - esnet  
  elastichq:
    container_name: elastichq
    image: elastichq/elasticsearch-hq
    ports:
      - 8080:5000
    environment:
      - HQ_DEFAULT_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - HQ_ENABLE_SSL=False
      - HQ_DEBUG=FALSE
    networks:
      - esnet  
networks:
  esnet:
```

However, when I open `ElasticHQ` the index name has been labeled as `filebeat-7.5.2-2020.02.10-000001` with a date stamp.  I have specified the `index` name as `Sample` in my `filebeat.yml`.  Is there something I am missing, or is this behavior normal?

Here is my `filebeat.yml`

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.json
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true 

#----------------------------- Elasticsearch output --------------------------------

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["elasticsearch:9200"]
  index: "sample-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"


setup.template.name: "sample"
setup.template.pattern: "sample-*"
```

It would be more practical to know something predefined so if I use Postman as opposed to ElasticHQ, I can start querying my data without having to look for the `index` name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Filebeat ILM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/ilm.html) might be taking over instead of the configured index name.

> Starting with version 7.0, Filebeat uses index lifecycle management by
>   default when it connects to a cluster that supports lifecycle
>   management. Filebeat loads the default policy automatically and
>   applies it to any indices created by Filebeat.

And when ilm is enabled Filebeat [Elasticsearch output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html#index-option-es) index settings are ignored

> The index setting is ignored when index lifecycle management is
>   enabled. If you’re sending events to a cluster that supports index
>   lifecycle management, see Configure index lifecycle management to
>   learn how to change the index name.

You might need to disable ILM or better yet configure your desired filename using ILM rollover_alias.